# ¿ Por que me imprime un 0 en el vector?

Tags: c++, array, vectores

**Tengo que crear un vectorC a partir de dos vectores ( vectorA y vectorB ) e ir llenando el nuevo vector con numeros sin ser repetidor, llevo intentando un buen rato pero me imprime un 0 en mitad del vector**

Ademas cuento con 3 archivos ( main.cpp, vectores.cpp(donde desarrollo el codigo), vectores.hpp(donde declaro el nombre de la funcion a desarrollar) ).

El main lo tengo declarado de esta manera:

```
#include "vectores.hpp"
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <string>
using namespace std;



int main(int argc, char** argv){

   int vectorA[5] = {1,2,3,4,5};
   int vectorB[5] = {1,7,8,9,10};
   int vectorC[10];
   int lenC = 0;
   int lenA = 5;
   int lenB = 5;

   //Lleno vector C
   llenarVectorC(vectorA, lenA, vectorB, lenB, vectorC, lenC);

   //Muestro vector C
   mostrarVectorC(vectorC, lenC);




   return 0;


}
```

el vectores.hpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

#ifndef vectores
#define vectores

void llenarVectorC(int vectorA[], int lenA, int vectorB[], int lenB, int vectorC[], int& lenC);
void mostrarVectorC(int vectorC[], int lenC);
```

Y el vectores.cpp:

```
#include "vectores.hpp"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;



void llenarVectorC(int vectorA[], int lenA, int vectorB[], int lenB, int vectorC[], int& lenC){

   //lleno vector C de vector A
   for( int i = 0; i < lenA; i++){
      if( vectorA[i] != vectorB[i]){
         if(vectorA[i] < vectorB[i]){
            vectorC[i] = vectorA[i];
            lenC++;
         }
      }else{
         vectorC[i] = vectorA[i];
         lenC++;
      }
   }

   //lleno vector C de vector B
   for( int i = 0; i < lenB; i++){
         vectorC[lenC+1] = vectorB[i];
         lenC++;
      }
}

void mostrarVectorC(int vectorC[], int lenC){
   for(int i=0; i < lenC; i++) {
      cout << vectorC[i] << endl;
   }
}
```

Y cuando lo imprimo me sale:
1
2
3
4
5
0  --> ?
1
7
8
9

Mi pregunta es por que sale un 0 en esa posicion ? (soy estudiante principiante)
Muchas gracias.

Comment: El problema reside en `lenC + 1`, cuando copias los elementos del vector B al C.

Comment: Solucionado, era eso, muchas gracias ( no se como marcarte como respuesta correcta xd)

Comment: Ah ya. Creí que te quedaría alguna duda más. Ahora lo escribo como respuesta y puedes marcarla

Answer (score 1):

Revisa en el segundo `for`. Según entiendo llevas la cuenta  en la variable `lenC` y también la usas para acceder a los elementos.

El espacio vacío se genera porque usas `lenC + 1`. Deberías tener cuidado con el índice al que intentas acceder porque podrías recibir un error si es mayor o igual a la cantidad de elementos o si es menor a 0.